# How to ensure that Ruby releases memory used by a Unix process after it is called?

Tags: ruby, unix, memory, memory-management

If I have an executable called from Ruby that consumes a significant amount of memory, such as:

```
puts `ls -lR /`
```

What happens when the process finishes? Does Unix collect the memory used by the process? Or is there a way to force Ruby to do so?

Answer (score 0):

*nix will do it as part of its normal processing, just as if you'd run it from the command-line.

The output of that command will be in Ruby's memory space and garbage collection will take care of it once it's no longer needed.

That said, as a programmer, we're supposed to recognize when something we're doing isn't scalable or efficient and find a way to do it that is scalable and efficient. People "DOS" their own systems regularly by not thinking out what they're doing. For instance, instead of using a recursive `ls` use [`Find.find`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html), which results in a more controllable and scalable piece of code.